# Where can I find data to create small sample drug database?

Tags: data-request, medical, python, drugs

For my diploma thesis I want to build an application to control medicine dosage and to do this I think about making sample database with like 1000 medicines with info most importantly about a dosage (4 times a day, every 4 hours...) and composition.

Does anyone know about some webpage that could easily provide me with this kind of information? I think about scraping it with Python. Or maybe somewhere there is already a sample database created like this.

Also, I think about making feature about what elements in medicine composition can be dangerous together. Something like: that you can't take some 3 medicines together. Maybe someone know and could recommend some webpage, article, maybe algorithm that could provide me more knowledge about this subject.

Comment: https://open.fda.gov/